# Swifter + Pandas: script does not move on after using swifter + apply()

Tags: python, pandas, swifter

I have a script that loads data from MySQL. After that a Pandas DataFrame is built. On it I do apply several `apply` methods.

When I run the script, without `swifter`, this is the ouput:

```
Duration Job0_sql:  0.011724
Duration Job0_df:   146.875376
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3316 entries, 0 to 3315
Data columns (total 57 columns):
id                       3316 non-null int64
routerName               3316 non-null object
routerLabel              3306 non-null object
[...]
```

Meaning that the SQL query lasted 0.011724 seconds. The whole process on the DataFrame, 146.9 seconds. Finally I do print `df.info()`. It also generates some plots (.jpegs) from the data itself.

After using `df.swifter.apply(.)` along the code, the output shows something different, and does not move on...

```
Duration Job0_sql:  0.012964
Pandas Apply: 100%|██████████████████████████| 48516/48516 [00:57<00:00, 845.45it/s]
Pandas Apply: 100%|██████████████████████████| 3316/3316 [00:00<00:00, 4463.01it/s]
```

I mean, after the `swifter` I'm not getting neither the time `Job0_df` nor the processing of the plots: the script just stops there after the progess bars.

Why is it that the code stops there? As per the [documentation](https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter), we only need to append the `swifter` keyword bebore the `apply` method.

Has anyone experienced something like this?